# How do embedded webservers control their hardware?

Tags: embedded

I have see applications (like my router) that allows access via http. How exactly does that work? I am guessing that there is there an embedded webserver that accepts http but how does it work after that? Is there some kind of app server that parses the commands and configure the incoming ports, etc? Where can I learn more about how this sort of thing works?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why would it work any different from a non-embedded web server?

Comment: Actually, your question make me think about this from a whole different perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web servers are a pretty popular embedded systems project. Most routers are more powerful than you might realize and a lot of people hack those. You could also build your own by programming a microcontroller and interfacing it with an ethernet chip like the ENC28J60. You can build mini web servers using tiny little 8-bit microcontrollers like PIC and AVR microcontrollers.

So, to get started, look at the various microcontrollers that hobbyists are using and jump in to a tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

YouTube video "lwIP TCP/IP stack for hard real-time systems" (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBk5wJ_8jEc) shows an embedded HTTP server based on the open source lwIP TCP/IP stack in action. You will see web pages served from an embedded device as well as some neat features of the embedded HTTP server, like Server-Side Includes (SSI) and Common Gateway Interface (CGI). SSI allows you to generate parts of a web page on-the-fly. This way the embedded target can generate dynamically changing content. The CGI allows communication from a browser (HTTP client) to the embedded target. That way you can update or change the target. Together these two features allow you to use a standard web browser as a remote user interface to an embedded device. This is all possible without any scripts running in the browser.

Of course you could also use executable content in your browser (such as JavaScript, Java applet, or others) to communicate with the target over the TCP/IP or UDP/IP.

The aforementioned video shows other useful features as well, like the target dynamically acquiring the IP address from a DHCP server and UDP communication to and from the embedded target. Links to complete source code and documentation of the embedded HTTP example are provided at the end of the video.

Answer (score 0):

You can find source to extremely basic web servers written in nearly any language.  You can even implement a very basic web server in something like awk and netcat. :)

The embedded system (depending on what it is) probably has a network stack just like any other to deliver messages to the server where they are parsed.  Many embedded systems definitely don't have a fully functional web server with modules, etc, etc (ie a full Apache/PHP/mod_rewrite/SSL/etc) set up.  But HTTP doesn't necessarily require all of that. :)

Answer (score -1):

Webserver parses the request, get the request parameters and passes to the other software to handle. In some small system, the number of concurrent requests are small, webserver can works as request handler also.

Example:
assume you want to change the LCD backlight.

```
1. [Client]--(request via browser: http://:/backlight?level=20)-->[WebServer]
2. [WebServer]--(call backlight controller application/thread with parameter: `level=20`)-->[Backlight Controller]
3. [Backlight Controller]--(change GPIO pins)-->[HW]
```

It depends on the scale of system, the backlight controller can be either a separate application or a part of webserver.

In [mongoose example](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/blob/master/examples/restful_server/restful_server.c)(as shown below), when you request such as `http://<ip>:<port>/api/v1/sum?n1=2&n2=4`, the `handle_sum_call` will be called. The `handle_sum_call` is implemented as a part of webserver.

```
static void ev_handler(struct mg_connection *nc, int ev, void *ev_data) {
  struct http_message *hm = (struct http_message *) ev_data;

  switch (ev) {
    case MG_EV_HTTP_REQUEST:
      if (mg_vcmp(&hm->uri, "/api/v1/sum") == 0) {
        handle_sum_call(nc, hm);                    /* Handle RESTful call */
      } else if (mg_vcmp(&hm->uri, "/printcontent") == 0) {
        char buf[100] = {0};
        memcpy(buf, hm->body.p,
               sizeof(buf) - 1 < hm->body.len? sizeof(buf) - 1 : hm->body.len);
        printf("%s\n", buf);
      } else {
        mg_serve_http(nc, hm, s_http_server_opts);  /* Serve static content */
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

You can move `handle_sum_call` out of webserver source code and create separate application, or [CGI script](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/cgic.html).